# Does/Will Entity Framework 6 support the new Sql Azure & Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

Does EF 6 support this method for authentication and if so what is the installation process and nuget packages to make it work?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like EF6 will support this without any changes, as it "only" requires .Net 4.6, the Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library for Microsoft SQL Server and a special connection string key, either:

```
Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;
```

Or

```
Authentication=Active Directory Password;
```

Comment: Does this include authentication in `migrate.exe` ?